# XML Encoding Intermittently Converting Characters?

Tags: .net, xml, encoding

I'm maintaining an old .Net 2.0 service that reads in data from a database, and serializes it to a XML file for conversion / output to a letter.

It has been running fine for years but will intermittently spit out a malformed file, where certain characters ( > and \b and \) will be converted rather than taken as their literal text counterparts.

I think this might be something to do with the encoding, but I can't get my head around why it does it intermittently. See examples between some of the files below (I've changed some of the names):

**Fine:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?encoding iso-8859-1?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='\\SERVER\FOLDER\bin\stylesheet\blabla.xsl'?>
```

**Malformed:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><?encoding iso-8859-1?><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='\SERVER\FOLDERin\stylesheet\blabla.xsl'?>
```

(I did note that the latter has standalone="yes" for some reason.. Could this affect it? Both these files have been generated from the same code.)

**Fine:**

```
<LetterText>&lt;FONT size=2 face=Arial&gt;
&lt;P style="MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px" dir=ltr align=left&gt;&lt;FONT size=2 face=Arial&gt;Dear Sir/Madam &lt;/P&gt;
&lt;P style="MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px" dir=ltr align=left&gt;&lt;FONT size=2 face=Arial&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;&lt;U&gt;ZERO FARE PASS&lt;/U&gt;&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/P&gt;
```

**Malformed:**

```
<LetterText>&lt;FONT size=2 face=Arial>
&lt;P style="MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px" dir=ltr align=left>&lt;FONT size=2 face=Arial>Dear Sir/Madam &lt;/P>
&lt;P style="MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px" dir=ltr align=left>&lt;FONT size=2 face=Arial>&lt;STRONG>&lt;U>BLABLABLA BLABLA&lt;/U>&lt;/STRONG>&lt;/FONT>&lt;/P>
```

Here's the code that I believe deals with this (Again I've changed some of the names around such as MyObject etc):

```
' create a serializer to create the xml output.
mySerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(myObject))

' serialize the pass batch to a stream in memory - allows us to edit the stream before outputting to a file
xmlMemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
mySerializer.Serialize(xmlMemoryStream, passes)

' load the xml from the memory stream into an XML Document
xmlMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
xmlDocument.Load(xmlMemoryStream)

' set the stylesheet instruction up and add it to the xml document.  if 
' the stylesheet is set on the print queue then use it
Dim processingInstruction As XmlProcessingInstruction
processingInstructionText = String.Format("type='text/xsl' href='{0}'", oPrintQueueType.stylesheet)
processingInstruction = xmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", processingInstructionText)
xmlDocument.InsertAfter(processingInstruction, xmlDocument.FirstChild)

' we must inform xml parses about special encoding we need to use to display
' unicode charaters in the xml with iso-8859-1 encoding
Dim instruction As XmlProcessingInstruction = xmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction("encoding", "iso-8859-1")
xmlDocument.InsertAfter(instruction, xmlDocument.FirstChild)
xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = True

' make a new file stream to the desired output file and use it to save the XML Document
' we must write unicode due to the characters in the encoded number string
stream = New System.IO.FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create)
xmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
xmlDocument.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter)
xmlTextWriter.Flush()
xmlTextWriter.Close()
```

I'm wondering whether to change the iso-8859-1 encoding to UTF-8. Either way though the point of what I'm not understanding is why it is intermittently different, with the same code, same data, but sometimes converts only certain special characters.

I know of many ways to exclude these (Such as the @ symbol in C#) but most require access to the raw data and individual elements. This app just picks it up and processes it.

Anyone else with any experience of this or could give me a pointer of where to focus?

Comment: It may be my lack of experience with XML, but why would you specify the encoding is iso-8859-1 and then create the `XmlTextWriter` with `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` instead of `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")`?

Comment: No idea to be honest. This system was developed years ago by someone else so it has a lot of quirks (including this one) that I'm trying to work out heh. I'll tweak it to use the same and give that a try, maybe that's the issue!

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you mate, I've only just returned back to work. You were right about why do it like that. I've changed the encoding to use UTF-8 and it seems to work now. (Problem hasn't reoccurred since).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

Changed this one line from:

```
Dim instruction As XmlProcessingInstruction = xmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction("encoding", "iso-8859-1")
```

To:

```
Dim instruction As XmlProcessingInstruction = xmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction("encoding", "UTF-8")
```

Haven't seen the corrupt XML problem reoccur since. Could be a coincidence as it was intermittent before (and had worked for 10+ years), but looks to be fixed at least.